# Abrir navegador en webView

Tags: android-studio, webview

He desarrollado una app con una WebView en la que se muestra una página de login. No obstante, como al ser de login no hay manera de saber cuál será la siguiente página a mostrar, por lo que se abre el navegador ajeno a la app. ¿Habría alguna posibilidad de que esta nueva página se abriera en el propio webView?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private TextView texto;
         private WebView web;
         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webV);

             //Habilitar JavaScript
             web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             web.loadUrl("https://www.launcher/");
         }
```

Comment: Pepito deberías añadir el código de tu webview para que podamos ayudarte, si se puede navegar dentro de tu webview sin salir de la app.

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con la etiqueta 'android-studio'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En onCreate añade el cliente para gestionas que se pueda sobrescribir la url y el control por si navegan hacia atrás.

```
web.loadUrl("https://www.launcher/");

    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                            view.loadUrl(url);

                        return true;
    //                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                    }

     web.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            switch (keyCode) {
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                                    if (web.canGoBack()) {
                                        web.goBack();
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Espero que con esto te funcione.